# Symfony form: testing widget breaks render of the widget

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

if I test my widget with the following code the widget does not render; not html widget in my page; only the label html

if I replace `{{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-input form-choice form-checkbox'}}) }}` with a `dump` I get the dump displayed so the if statement works

If I remove the if my widget is rendered so looks like the if statement is breaking the rendering ?

```
<div class="custom-select">
     {% if 'checkbox' in (form_widget(form)) %}
         {{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-input form-choice form-checkbox'}}) }}
     {% else %}
         {{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-input form-choice'}}) }}
      {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify form item ?

```
{{ form_widget(form.inputname) }}
```

Comment: It is not possible to do that because the code from the question is just a `theme` so for all `form.vars.block_prefixes[1] == 'choice'`